# possibility of scala-virtualized in Eclipse with Scala >=2.11

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, virtualization, staging

I followed this guide: http://lamplmscore.epfl.ch/mediawiki/index.php/Eclipse_IDE_with_Scala-virtualized

in order to use the virtualized (-Yvirtualize ) plugin inside the eclipse compiler. This works for a nightly build of Scala 2.10 which is *old* and lacks features like `implicit classes`. Does anyone know of a way to work with newer versions of Scala with the virtualize plugin *AND* eclipse?

Comment: [As far as I can judge there is at least 2.10.2 version of it](https://github.com/adriaanm/scala-virtualized-tutorial/commit/efdb4c0a9fae7ff011ebc99acb0890dc7547f5c6) (I've checked and it is presented in maven central too), which means you can perfectly use implicit classes and a bunch of other features introduced in 2.10. Don't know anything regardless future status of scala virtualized, though.

Comment: Not sure what you are seeing in that link. Does this have anything to do with the eclipse plugin?

Comment: yeah, you're right. I totally missed the point is that it's about *Eclipse plugin*, not scala virtualized per se.

Comment: Implicit classes were added in 2.10. How come they are missing from your build?

Comment: This confused me as well, but sadly, they simply aren't there in the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to be bringing bad news:

The Eclipse IDE for Scala-virtualized has not been updated in the last 2 years, so it's not expected to be usable (Source: I maintained the EclipseIDE for scala-virtualized) -- I updated the [wiki](http://lamplmscore.epfl.ch/mediawiki/index.php/Eclipse_IDE_with_Scala-virtualized).

Regarding 2.11, please see Alexey's comment (and answer) below.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this: scala-virtualized 2.11.2 is available now (and while it probably won't work with Eclipse, you _can_ use it in IDEA).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov why not have a separate answer for this so it can bubble to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Scala-virtualized [has been updated to 2.11.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.virtualized/scala-library/2.11.2) now. You can definitely use it in IDEA, at least (just make sure the Scala-virtualized `scala-{library,reflect,compiler}.jar` are above the non-virtualized versions in `Dependencies` tab under `Project Settings -> Modules`). I don't know if you can use it in Eclipse, but it might be possible using [Scala installations support](http://scala-ide.org/blog/scala-installations.html) (see under `BYOS (Bring Your Own Scala)`).